# Javascript AJAX return special characters

Tags: javascript, ajax, character-encoding

I've been trying to return special characters from an AJAX request to a PHP script.

The responding character string : abcde1’2’3’4’5“6”7–8é9é10’11’12’13ñ14ñ15’16ñ17ñ18 19 20é21é22í23ñ24ñ25’26ñ27ó28ú29’fghij

Using a JavaScript alert, it displays: abcde1â2â3â4â5â6â7â8Ã©9Ã©10â11â12â13Ã±14Ã±15â16Ã±17Ã±18 19 20Ã©21Ã©22Ã­23Ã±24Ã±25â26Ã±27Ã³28Ãº29âfghij

The code is below:

**HTML File:**

```
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0      Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
<head>
<meta http-equiv="content-type" content="text/html; charset=ISO-8859-1"/> 
    <title></title>
    <script src="js/phpTest.js" charset="ISO-8859-1" type="text/javascript"></script>
</head>
<body>
    <input id="Submit1" type="submit" value="submit" onclick=" initXHR();return false;" />
</body>
</html>
```

**JS File:**

```
var xhr;
//;charset=ISO-8859-1
function initXHR() {
    getXHRobj();
    xhr.open('POST', 'phpinfo.php', true);
    xhr.setRequestHeader("Content-type", "application/x-www-form-urlencoded");
    xhr.setRequestHeader("Content-length", 10);
    xhr.setRequestHeader("Connection", "close");
    xhr.send("");
    return false;
}

function getXHRobj() {
    if (window.XMLHttpRequest) {
        xhr = new XMLHttpRequest();
    }
    else if (window.ActiveXObject) {
        xhr = new ActiveXObject("Msxml2.XMLHTTP");
    }
    else {
        throw new Error("Ajax is not supported by this browser");
    }
    xhr.onreadystatechange = function XHRresp() {
        if (xhr.readyState == 4) {
            if (xhr.status >= 200 && xhr.status < 300) {
                document.write("1. " + xhr.responseText);
            }
            else {
                alert(xhr.responseText);
            }
        }
    }
}
```

**And PHP file:**

```
<?php 
header("Content-Type: text/html;charset=ISO-8859-1");

print "abcde1’2’3’4’5“6”7–8é9é10’11’12’13ñ14ñ15’16ñ17ñ18 19 20é21é22í23ñ24ñ25’26ñ27ó28ú29’fghij";
?>
```

Thank you,
deDogs

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your charset in the HTML code may say ISO-8859-1 but are you sure you saved the data in ISO-8859-1?  The data may be saved in UTF-8 or Windows CP-1252

Comment: In PHP when I print this string "abcde1’2’3’4’5“6”7–8é9é10’11’12’13ñ14ñ15’16ñ17ñ18 19 20é21é22í23ñ24ñ25’26ñ27ó28ú29’fghij" Would this be considered UTF-8 or Windows CP-1252? I think, I'm responding with explicit string?

Comment: The editor you used to create the PHP code saved the file (including your special string) to disk.  What editor are you using?  Most editors have a setting/preference/option for setting the charset to use/save/edit in.

Comment: Thank you Mark, I'm using Notepad creating the html, php, and js files. I tried reducing the string to a single character( ñ ), which the html page doesn't display correctly. Thank you

Comment: @deDogs  Did that fix your problem? If that fixes your problem you might want to click the checkmark next to my answer so that other users that have the same problem will realize what was the problem.

Answer (score 1):

Looks like the text you receive gets a different encoding style.

May be this might help you.

Try changing the content-type while placing the request.

```
xhr.setRequestHeader("Content-type", "text/richtext");
```

Or anything suitable for the content being transferred. Following link might help you chose the content type.

http://www.utoronto.ca/web/htmldocs/book/book-3ed/appb/mimetype.html#text

Comment: Be careful that "text/richtext " may be treated differently that "text/richtext".  Not sure if that extra space will break what you're trying to do.

Comment: I agree. Let me remove the extra space.